# What programs or websites solve linear integer or goal programming problems?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, operations-research

I don't think I can use Excel. My solver doesn't work so I can't even use Excel for regular linear programming.

Something like [this](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html) but for integer or goal programming.

[This](http://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/simplex.aspx) seems to allow integer programming, but it doesn't work sometimes. Any alternatives?

Comment: [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/) certainly is able to do what you want, however it might be hard to use if you have no programming experience at all.

Comment: @Eff What do you mean? If I just plug in the obj func and constraints...do I get the answer as if I used Solver in Excel?

Comment: I never use Excel, so I cannot relate to that. I'm simply saying that you can solve the types of problems you are talking about (e.g. integer programming) with GAMS.

Comment: @Eff What do you mean? If I just plug in the obj func and constraints...do I get the answer?